# Bourne shell: how should I terminate a script from within a while loop reading from a pipe?

Tags: sh

Here is /bin/sh behaviour that surprised me, "exit" failing to exit:

```
$ cat sh_exit_from_while_pipe 
#!/bin/sh
echo foobar | while read blabla
do
    echo >&2 "Calling 'exit 2'"
    exit 2
    echo >&2 "It seems 'exit' did not terminate the while loop?"
done
echo >&2 "It seems 'exit' did not terminate the script?"

$ ./sh_exit_from_while_pipe 
Calling 'exit 2'
It seems 'exit' did not terminate the script?
```

Empirically I notice exit is leaving the while loop, but not the whole script. So my best guess at the moment is that, maybe, the pipe forks a new shell as subprocess, and exit only terminates the subprocess?

What would be a good way to terminate properly? (I might rewrite this entirely to avoid the "echo foobar |" - which might avoid this problem, but I'm still interested in how this might be more directly addressed.)

Comment: Your loop is in a subshell (which isn't necessarily a new process); *that's* what the `exit` command exits. In this particular example,  you can use a here document rather than a pipe to provide the input.

Comment: You have a same log `"It seems 'exit' did not terminate the while loop?"` inside the subshell and after the while loop. The exit does exit the subshell (created by the pipeline)

Comment: @inian the `echo`s are *different* in this case, but yes the subshell does exit as expected. (The `echo` that runs is the one at the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point where you execute `exit 2`, you can't tell how many "levels" of shell need to exit. The best you can do is use the exit status of the loop to see if that level should exit as well. For example,

```
echo foobar | while read blabla; do
    x=$(foo)
    if [ "$x" = bar ]; then
       exit 0  # We're done with the loop, success
    elif [ "$x" = gulp ]; then
       exit 1  # We're done with the loop, failure
    else
       exit 2  # We're done with the script, abort!
    fi
done

case $? in
  2) printf 'Fatal error in loop, exiting\n' >&2; exit 1 ;;
  *) printf 'Loop result %d, continuing\n' ;;
esac

printf 'Continuing script...'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value returned by the while loop.  eg:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! echo foobar | { while read blabla
do
    echo >&2 "Calling 'exit 2'"
    exit 2
    echo >&2 "It seems 'exit' did not terminate the while loop?"
done
exit 0
};  then
    echo >&2 "The loop failed"
    exit 1
fi
echo >&2 "It seems 'exit' did not terminate the script?"
```

(Note that the brackets and the `exit 0` are not actually necessary, just added to be explicit.)